# Using eq_refl to get an "x = x" hypothesis

Tags: coq

In short, is this possible?

I'm trying to prove that cancellation works in a group.

I have

```
a, b, x : G
H: a <+> x = b <+> x
```

and I would like to prove

```
a = b
```

My idea was to get a hypothesis

```
H2: a <+> x <+> i x = a <+> x <+> i x
```

(`i` is the inverse function).

---

I have tried

```
pose proof eq_refl (a <+> x <+> i x) as H.
```

but this does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal really looks like what you posted, then your tactic should fail because it is reusing the name `H`.  If this is not the problem, then it would help to know what error message Coq displays.

Comment: In addition, the proof term is missing parentheses around it.

Comment: @AntonTrunov I think that is not a problem, actually: I just ran a similar snippet on my machine, and it worked.

Comment: Oh, yes, you are right -- I confused it with `specialize`, which requires parens

Comment: It was exactly this typo. Thanks!

Comment: Great that you got the solution!  However, you then edited your question to remove your mistake, and then the answers to the question as it stands now does not make any sense.  I wouldn't consider this good practice or helpful, although I can understand the urge to do it.

Comment: I can't remember why I did this - I think, at first, I thought that there was still an error remaining even once I corrected the typo (hence why I had kept 'but it does not seem to work') - but it appears not. So I have reverted!